# How can I call a non-static member function of a class from a static member function of another class?

Tags: c++, static-members, pointer-to-member

I have a class with a static function (it must be static) that must call some registered member functions of instances of other classes:

```
class MyCalledClass
{
    MyCallerClass& caller;
    void functionToCall();
    void register()
    {
        caller.setFunctionToCall(&MyCalledClass::functionToCall);
    }
    MyCalledClass(MyCallerClass& mcc,...):caller{mcc}
    {
        register();
    }
}

class MyCallerClass
{
    static void (MyCalledClass::*pointerToMember)();
    
    static void call()
    {
        *pointerToMember();
    }

    void setFunctionToCall(void (MyCalledClass::*pt)())
    {
        pointerToMember = pt;
    }
}
/*...*/
MyCallerClass caller{...};
MyCalledClass called{caller,...};
```

Why does the compiler says "invalid use of unary '*' on pointer to member" on the *pointerToMember() call in MyCallerClass::call?
Setting pointerToMember as non-static is not allowed because it is used inside a static member function.
Removing the '*' operator I get the error "must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'MyCallerClass::pointerToMember (...)', so I guess a reference is missing, but I don't understand which one.
What kind of reference is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Find out that the missing reference is a reference to the instance of MyCalledClass, so I modified the code this way:

```
class MyCalledClass
{
    MyCallerClass& caller;
    void functionToCall();
    void register()
    {
        caller.setFunctionToCall(&MyCalledClass::functionToCall);
    }
    MyCalledClass(MyCallerClass& mcc,...):caller{mcc}
    {
        register();
    }
}

class MyCallerClass
{
    static void (MyCalledClass::*pointerToMember)();
    static MyCalledClass* calledInstance;
    
    static void call()
    {
        calledInstance->*pointerToMember();
    }

    void setFunctionToCall(void (MyCalledClass::*pt)(), MyCalledClass* ptToCalled)
    {
        calledInstance = ptToCalled;
        pointerToMember = pt;
    }
}
/*...*/
MyCallerClass caller{...};
MyCalledClass called{caller,...};
```

Suggestions on how to improve this solution or other ways to do so are welcome.

Comment: it is not clear why the called needs to have a reference of the caller. If the action is trigger by the caller object just pass the std::function pointing on the method and reduce coupling. If the action is triggered by the called you should ask yourself if you are re-inventing the obverser pattern